Android Management API: Test Device Fails to Enroll for BYOD Deployment
I am trying to enroll a test device using the Android Management API as part of a BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) deployment. This device is intended for testing purposes before deploying the solution to production.

The issue is that the device fails to enroll despite following the usual process. Here are some important details:

This is a test device that I have used for Android Management API enrollment multiple times in the past.
The enrollment process used to work without any issues before.
I am using the same setup and enrollment token generation logic that previously worked.

Steps I’ve tried to resolve this issue:

Restarted the device to ensure no cached data interferes with enrollment.
Generated a fresh enrollment token.
Verified that the API configuration and policies are correct.

Is there a limitation or restriction related to re-enrolling a device multiple times? Could there be a problem with the test device itself, or does the Android Management API impose any restrictions in such scenarios?
( Note: I cannot reset the device as its my personal device that I am using now )
Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.
